# Can I use Dll from VS 6.0 in VS 2010 C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-c++-6

I am not pro in C++ programming and I am not sure if I am asking the right question. 
I have a DLL from which I have to use a few functions and types. This DLL was created in Microsoft VisuaL Studio 6.0.
I have VS2010, is it a straight forward approach to create a new project in VS 2010 C++ and use above mentioned Dll in the project ?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
CPP

Comment: Which language was the DLL created in? Is it statically linked or dynamically linked?

Comment: The DLL is created in C++ Visual Studio 6.0. The file is .DLL, not sure how was it linked. Is there a way to find out ?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the function calls in the DLL take standard C type and not classes you are ok for sure.

If MFC classes are passed to the DLL, you are probably not OK as classes probably changed from VC6 to VS2010.

If non MFC classes/structs are passed to the DLL you may be ok as long as you pack the structures to the right alignment.